# Force analysis of silver atom in Stern–Gerlach experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In this experiment we only consider the force at z direction, but $\vec B$ field gradient doesn't  exclusively exist at z direction according to Maxwell's equations. So why don't we see the splitting in other directions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point made by Otto Stern in the [original publication (german)](http://positron.physik.uni-halle.de/F-Praktikum/PDF/39_zphys1921v7_249_stern.pdf) is that the contribution of $\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial y}$ can be neglected when averaging over a suitable period of time.

In that case the force, aka the negative gradient of $\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}$ is only relevant along the z-axis, but technically you are then talking about an time-average of the force.